# How to solve CORS policy blocking when connecting front end to Java Spring Boot API?

Tags: java, spring, api, frontend, backend

How to connect my front end (html/css/js) to my back end (java spring boot, jpa)?
after connecting them, how do I upload the fullstack application onto aws?

I tried using fetch from http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html to http://localhost:8080.

But the error says: been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled..

I have googled this, and people said I can't do that because two different hosts.

I am not sure what to do now. I am new to backend development and api.

My goal right now is (front end -> api -> java spring boot -> postgres). and upload this on aws or something. idk what im saying anymore.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just few api services to be available from your front, add this to the wanted controller methods :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://127.0.0.1:5500/")
```

If you want a global configuration, you can do this on your @SpringBootApplication class (or a @Configuration class) :

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOriginPatterns("http://127.0.0.1:5500").allowCredentials(true);
        }
    };
}
```

You have a complete guide there:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/