# How can i solve proxy (CORS) problem on production

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js, cors

I developed an app on Vuejs. I have Spring Boot on backend. I was using devServer proxy like that

```
devServer: {
proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: 'http://localhost:8087/',
          changeOrigin: true,
          pathRewrite: {
            '^/api': ''
          }
        }}
```

but now i need to build and deploy it. When i didnt changed anything, my requests going to 'api/login' or 'api/register' etc.. Thats need to be localhost:8087/login or localhost:8087/register. What should i do? When i didnt use proxy its giving CORS error. Can you help me, Thank you.

I need a solve cors problem on Production Vuejs build

Comment: For security reasons, browsers don't allow "shady-website.com" to make ajax requests to "descent-website.com", unless "descent-website.com" allows the "shady-website.com" domain to call it. General info on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
 
Baeldung has a very good tutorial on this for Spring Boot: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors.

In an ideal world, front-end and back-end get hosted on the same domain.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76292114/how-to-solve-cors-policy-blocking-when-connecting-front-end-to-java-spring-boot/76292932#76292932

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deployed my frontend with expressjs proxy then its fixed. Thanks for comments

Answer (score 0):

try @CrossOrigin("*") in your controller